# How do I declare a variable of enum type in Kotlin?

Tags: enums, kotlin

Following [the documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/enum-classes.html), I created an enum class:

```
enum class BitCount public constructor(val value : Int)
{
  x32(32),
  x64(64)
}
```

Then, I'm trying to declare a variable in some function:

```
val bitCount : BitCount = BitCount(32)
```

But there is a compilation error:

> Error:(18, 29) Kotlin: Enum types cannot be instantiated

How do I declare a variable of BitCount type and initialize it from an `Int`?

Comment: BTW, you don't have to use the full constructor syntax for simple cases, so the word `constructor` is redundant. It may be done with just `public enum class BitCount(..)`

Comment: If you still want to create an instance of the Enum given the numeric value, you can (but it is more "find the instance given a numeric value"):  http://stackoverflow.com/a/34625163/3679676

Comment: for new comers. read this tutorial on enums in Kotlin. http://developine.com/enum-classes-in-kotlin-example/

Comment: All ENUM constants have to be declared inside the enum class definition. What you are trying to do (creating object) is for a regular class, not of ENUM. Refer https://www.tutorialkart.com/kotlin/enum-classes-in-kotlin/ for examples on Kotlin Enum.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

As stated in other answers, you can reference any value of the `enum` that exists by name, but not construct a new one.  That does not prevent you from doing something similar to what you were trying...

```kotlin
// wrong, it is a sealed hierarchy, you cannot create random instances
val bitCount : BitCount = BitCount(32)

// correct (assuming you add the code below)
val bitCount = BitCount.from(32)
```

If you were wanting to find the instance of the `enum` based on the numeric value `32` then you could scan the values in the following way.  Create the `enum` with a `companion object` and a `from()` function:

```kotlin
enum class BitCount(val value : Int)
{
    x16(16),
    x32(32),
    x64(64);

    companion object {
        fun from(findValue: Int): BitCount = BitCount.values().first { it.value == findValue }
    }
}
```

Then call the function to get a matching existing instance:

```kotlin
val bits = BitCount.from(32) // results in BitCount.x32
```

Nice and pretty.  Alternatively in this case you could create the name of the `enum` value from the number since you have a predictable relationship between the two, then use `BitCount.valueOf()`.  Here is the new `from()` function within the companion object.

```kotlin
fun from(findValue: Int): BitCount = BitCount.valueOf("x$findValue")
```

Comment: Nice! One might want to use `valueOf`, though; then it looks like we'd overload `valueOf(String)`.

Comment: Variants: 1) `when` over the possible inputs, dealing with `else` properly. 2) Use `firstOrNull` and make the return value of `from` optional. 3) [Preprocess a map](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37795810/539599).

Comment: for new comers. read this tutorial on enums in Kotlin. http://developine.com/enum-classes-in-kotlin-example/

Comment: Your "from()" method should be in the Kotlin library!

Answer (score 14):

Enum instances could be declared only inside enum class declaration.

If you want to create new BitCount just add it as shown below:

```
enum class BitCount public constructor(val value : Int)
{
    x16(16),
    x32(32),
    x64(64)
}
```

and use everywhere as `BitCount.x16`.

Comment: "enum class BitCount(val value: Int)" is enough, because you cant create instance outside of the enum

Comment: I see, I thought that enum class constructor allows creating of an instance of enum by passing corresponding value to it.

Comment: That's what classes are for.

Comment: BitCount.valueOf("x32") if you only have the name at runtime

Comment: An enum is like a "sealed" class hierarchy in a way, in that you cannot create randomly new instances outside of those pre-defined.

Comment: If the original intent of the asker is to find the enum given the integer value, this does not answer the question.  It is easily possible.  See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34625163/3679676

Answer (score 8):

What about:

```
enum class BitCount constructor(val value : Int)
{
    x32(32),
    x64(64);

    companion object {
         operator fun invoke(rawValue: Int) = BitCount.values().find { it.rawValue == rawValue }
    }
}
```

Then you can use it like you proposed:

```
val bitCount = BitCount(32)
```

And it will return null if value is not found in enum cases

Answer (score 0):

If you really do want to give the ability to construct arbitrary instances, use a [value class](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/inline-classes.html) instead of an enum.

```kotlin
@JvmInline value class BitCount(val value: Int) {
    companion object {
        val x32 = BitCount(32)
        val x64 = BitCount(64)
    }
}
```

Value classes are always compared by their value, rather than by identity. You can call `BitCount(32)`, but the result will always be the same as the existing `x32` instance, as there's only one possible instance with that value.

Using this approach, you can create any `BitCount` value you like, for example `BitCount(31)` or `BitCount(-1)`. Use this approach if the set of possible values can vary at runtime or can't be practically represented by listing them all out in the code. Use an enum if you have a small, fixed set of allowed values that are known at compile-time.