# Kotlin: How to check if enum contains a given String without messing with Exceptions?

Tags: kotlin

Why there is no `contains` method in enum classes (as well as in Java)? And how to implement it elegantly? Now I'm using this ugly approach:

```
val contains: Boolean = 
    try {
        MyEnum.valueOf("some string")
        true
    } catch (e: IllegalArgumentException) {
        false
    }
```

Answer (score 62, accepted):

### `enumContains`

You can create an `enumContains` function similar to [Hound Dog](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1068649/hound-dog)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41845064/3255152) but using [reified type parameters](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/inline-functions.html#reified-type-parameters) instead.

You cannot create a JVM independent solution in Kotlin 1.0 but you can in Kotlin 1.1 using [`enumValues`](https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2017/01/kotlin-1-1-beta-is-here/).

#### Kotlin 1.1

```
/**
 * Returns `true` if enum T contains an entry with the specified name.
 */
inline fun <reified T : Enum<T>> enumContains(name: String): Boolean {
    return enumValues<T>().any { it.name == name}
}
```

#### Kotlin 1.0

```
/**
 * Returns `true` if enum T contains an entry with the specified name.
 */
inline fun <reified T : Enum<T>> enumContains(name: String): Boolean {
    return T::class.java.enumConstants.any { it.name == name}
}
```

#### Usage

```
enumContains<MyEnum>("some string") // returns true or false
```

### `enumValueOfOrNull`

If you also need the actual enum entry then you might consider creating an `enumValueOfOrNull` function instead.

#### Kotlin 1.1

```
/**
 * Returns an enum entry with the specified name or `null` if no such entry was found.
 */
inline fun <reified T : Enum<T>> enumValueOfOrNull(name: String): T? {
    return enumValues<T>().find { it.name == name }
}
```

#### Kotlin 1.0

```
/**
 * Returns an enum entry with the specified name or `null` if no such entry was found.
 */
inline fun <reified T : Enum<T>> enumValueOfOrNull(name: String): T? {
    return T::class.java.enumConstants.find { it.name == name }
}
```

#### Usage

```
enumValueOfOrNull<MyEnum>("some string")
```

Comment: Yeah that's much better using `reified` (having an extension function on KClass isn't very pretty!).  On a semi-related side note, along with `enumConstants`, 1.1 is bringing a whole bag of [reflection goodies](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/commit/ed1490dbc43f88696f82e5307df43269ecbb32b1)!

Answer (score 19):

You can just take `values` Array of your enum and use contains over it. For example:

```
Planets.values().map { it.name }.contains("EARTH")
```

But for this you need to have correct string value so you might uppercase it before search.

If you want to find enum by its value take a look at the [Reverse Lookup](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37795810/2392960) for enums.

**Edit:**

As @JamesBassett suggested you can optimize it to stop looking once it finds a match.

```
Planets.values().any { it.name == "EARTH" }
```

Comment: I'd probably simplify to `Planets.values().any { it.name == "EARTH" }` (you want it to stop looking once its found a match instead of looking through the  whole list)

Answer (score 3):

You could do something like this:

```
fun <T : Enum<*>> KClass<T>.contains(value: String): Boolean {
    return this.java.enumConstants.any { it.name == value }
}

MyEnum::class.contains("some string")
```

Answer (score 1):

or if you are really adventurous

```
enum MyEnum {
    MY_1, MY_2;
   
    companion object {

        fun isInEnum(someString: String) {
            return try {
                valueOf(someString)
                true
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                false
            }
        }
    }
}
```